# nullPointerException on calling Texture.update

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

When trying to update a Texture I get a nullPointerException. my code is

```
    t.updateImage(gl, new TextureData(Client.profile,
            GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            camWidth,
            camHeight,
            0,
            GL.GL_RGB,
            GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            testBuf(),
            null
            ));
```

with testBuf() being:

```
    public IntBuffer testBuf(){

    int[] ints = new int[bufWidth*bufHeight];

    for(int i = 0; i < bufWidth*bufHeight; i++){
        ints[i] = 155;
    }

    IntBuffer intBuf = IntBuffer.wrap(ints);

    return intBuf;
}
```

Beforehand, eclipse shows no errors whatsoever, but when I run the program it throws a NullPointerException on the line with t.updateImage(...
It might also be worth notiing that I am calling this method from my display method (Even though it didn't work in the init method either).

What am I missing? Is there a problem with the way I am creating the buffer?

Comment: try to take `testbuf()` return in a variable and check if its `NULL`

Comment: did that, it got past the != null statement, and printed out as "java.nio.HeapIntBuffer[pos=0 lim=307200 cap=307200]"

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and a SSCCE: http://sscce.org You should use com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers to create buffers for JOGL. Check if t or gl is null.

Comment: as it turns out, the problem was that t was null, because I messed up in init method. thanks.